# Inserting char string into another char string

Tags: c

Ok, so I have a char stringA and char stringB, and I want to be able to insert stringB into stringA at point x.

```
char *stringA = "abcdef";
char *stringB = "123";
```

with a product of `"ab123cdef"`

does anyone know how to do this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Also, you tagged this C++. If it's C++ and it's not homework, why not just use std::string?

Comment: I know how to do it with a std::string, and ya it is homework

Comment: If this is homework (or even if it weren't), I would suggest that you edit your post to include what you have already tried, and where you've gotten stuck. As it is, you are simply asking someone else to do your homework for you.

Comment: C or C++?  The right (well, *preferred*) answer will be different for each.

Comment: @Brian: ...why bother? Unless the larger SO community votes down poorly asked homework questions *and* answers that provide the solutions to those same homework questions, there is no reason to go to the trouble. Why ask a man how to fish, when you can just ask him to hand you a fish?

Comment: @mcl: if we let people do these things for themselves, they will become good programmers. We don't need more competition.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
char * strA = "Blahblahblah", * strB = "123", strC[50];
int x = 4;
strncpy(strC, strA, x);
strC[x] = '\0';
strcat(strC, strB);
strcat(strC, strA + x);
printf("%s\n", strC);
```

Explanation:

1. You declare the two strings you will be joining, plus a third string into which you will put them.
2. You declare an integer to tell the program after how many characters you wish to insert the second string into the first.
3. The strncpy function copies the first x characters into strC. You have to add the null ('\0') character at the end, otherwise you'll probably get rubbish.
4. Strcat to copy the second string.
5. Another strcat to copy the remaining part of the first string (strA + x).

Hope that helps.

Remark: remember to make strC long enough to contain both strA and strC, otherwise you'll produce a segmentation fault. You may do this by declaring the string as an array, like in my example.

Comment: ya i just used:
 char* strC = (char*)malloc(strlen(strA) + strlen(strB_);
perfect answer thank you!

Comment: @Sj, don't forget the null char!

Comment: @Sj: it should be char * strC = malloc(strlen(strA)+strlen(strB)+1). You forgot about the additional character for the '\0'. It might seem to work, but you have a chance of overwriting a byte of something that's not your string. I'm not sure gdb will catch this, but electric fence will complain.

Comment: I would think this to be the best solution because it does not malloc memory. If you malloc memory then you must free it or you have created a memory leak. And if you do free the memory malloc'd then either, you must use it in the immediate scope in which it was created, or send the pointer elsewhere where it must be tracked so it can later be freed. If you create a oversized array then the OS will deal with freeing the memory.

Comment: Using strcpy and strcat in examples is a bad idea. It propagates the unsafe use that leads to many critical vulnarabilities, around for decades now. Please remember to use strlcpy, and related members of the "l" sort!

Comment: why not just zero initialize an array? `char strC[50] = {0};`

Answer (score 9):

stringA and stringB are both pointers - they contain the starting address for a blob of memory.  The memory they are pointing to contain continuous strings of characters: "abcdef" and "123" respectively.  Since strings are contiguous blocks memory (meaning that the memory location of a given character is one byte after the previous) you can't insert more characters into the middle of a string without first moving some characters.  In your case you can't even really do this, since the amount of memory allocated for each string is exactly large enough to hold JUST that string (ignoring padding).

What you are going to have to do is copy the strings to another block of memory, one that you have allocated for that purpose, and copy them so that the second string starts x characters into the first string.

Several other SO users have posted code-solutions but I think you should try and find the exact solution on your own (and hopefully my high-level explanation of what's going on will help).

Answer (score 3):

Here a more general solution.

**Note** that `destination` must have enough space in memory to add seed (e.g. an heap-allocated array of size grater than `strlen(seed)+strlen(destination)` ). So, concerning the question, you have to create a larger array.

```
/* 
    destination: a NULL terminated string
    pos: where insert seed
    seed: a NULL terminated string
*/
void insertString(char* destination, int pos, char* seed)
{
    char * strC;

    strC = (char*)malloc(strlen(destination)+strlen(seed)+1);
    strncpy(strC,destination,pos);
    strC[pos] = '\0';
    strcat(strC,seed);
    strcat(strC,destination+pos);
    strcpy(destination,strC);
    free(strC);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int insert_pos = 5;
int product_length = strlen(stringA) + strlen(stringB) + 1;
char* product = (char*)malloc(product_length);
strncpy(product, stringA, insert_pos);
product[insert_pos] = '\0';
strcat(product, stringB);
strcat(product, stringA + insert_pos);
...
free(product);
```

Comment: If you want to write safe software, avoid strcpy and such, and instead use the "l" variants where you pass the size of the modified string, making sure you don't get accidendal overflows that can crash your app and make it vulnerable to attacks. e.g: `strlcpy (product, ..., sizeof(product)`. If you find that cumbersome, make yourself a Macro for it: `#define STRCPY(a,b) strlcpy (a, b, sizeof(a))`. Same for strcat etc.!

Answer (score -1):

```
char *strInsert(char *str1, const char *str2, int pos) {
    size_t l1 = strlen(str1);
    size_t l2 = strlen(str2);

    if (pos <  0) pos = 0;
    if (pos > l1) pos = l1;

    char *p  = str1 + pos;
    memmove(p + l2, p, l1 - pos);
    memcpy (p, str2,  l2);
    return str1;
}
```